# How should i get result used regex and split method in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a String

```java
String s = "XXXX....XXX.....XX";
```

I want the following results.

```java
String[] strings = {"XXXX", "XXX", "XX"};
```

I tried the following.

```java
String[] split = s.split("[\\.*]");
```

i got the result

[image]

How should I do this if possible?

Comment: Use `s.split("\\.+");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split with multiple dots and avoid empty items, you can use

```java
String[] chunks = s.split("\\.+");
String[] chunks = s.replaceFirst("^\\.+", "").split("\\.+");
```

**NOTE**: the `replaceFirst("^\\.+", "")` is necessary in case there are leading dots. If you are sure there can be no leading dots, you may use `s.split("\\.+")` alone.

*Details*:

- `^` -  start of string
- `\.+` - one or more dot chars (in a Java string literal, the backslash is doubled)

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/266wpO):

```java
String s = "...XXXX....XXX.....XX...";
String[] chunks = s.replaceFirst("^\\.+", "").split("\\.+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chunks));
```

Comment: Wow O_o.....Thank you very so much :) You are so cool !

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```java
String[] results = string.split("(?:\\Q.\\E)+");
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/G3bI6u/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \Q                       start of a literal string pattern
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        a literal dot
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \E                       end of a literal string pattern
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
```